# Google Chrome could not load the webpage because myPortalapps-12812b1f934c6c.myPortal.apps.com took too long to respond

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Trying hello world hosted app but getting this error on deployment,

> Google Chrome could not load the webpage because
>   myPortalapps-12812b1f934c6c.myPortal.apps.com took too long to respond

I can ping `myPortalapps.myPortal.apps.com` but not `myPortalapps-12812b1f934c6c.myPortal.apps.com`

Comment: Had issues with dns, I had to re set it up to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had some similar problems facing sharepoint web app's [this forum post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/d923928d-ab0c-400b-8c3f-2bebc3e5d385/sharepoint-site-taking-too-long-to-load-or-not-load-at-all) helped me out alot:

> When troubleshooting performance issues where more than one
>   person/computer is impacted, the first place I like to start is by
>   running a sniffer like Fiddler: 
>   http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp
>
> Fiddler will let you now exactly how long it takes to load the page,
>   and break down each and every resource that is also loaded in order to
>   render the page.  This is also a great tool for determining what is
>   and what is not being cached.
>
> I take the output of this and see if there is anything being loaded
>   that I'm not expecting.  Every once in awhile I'll see where a user
>   might reference an image housed on an external site or server.  This
>   can have serious consequences to load times.
>
> I also look at the actual SharePoint page to see if there are any
>   hidden web parts loading list data.  Most users accidentaly click
>   "Close" and not "Delete" so those web parts or list views are still
>   there.  In some cases there could be significant data being loaded and
>   just not displayed.
>
> Likewise I'll also take a look to see if any audiences are being used
>   since Audiences can be used to show/hide content.